# Remove white box over text in Firefox on CSS shape

Tags: html, css

I have created a bit of a unique shape in CSS for my site. See the demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/p8jfnwa0/

However, I have noticed in Firefox that a white block appears over the word `News`. How do I get rid of this?

```css
    button {
        font-size: 1em;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #1588cb;
        color: #1588cb;
        font-weight: 400;
        height: 60px;
        width: 300px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 25px 0 50px 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        -o-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
    .full-circle {
        display:block;
        border: 1px solid #1588cb;
        width: 45px;
        /*
        -moz-border-radius: 45px / 36px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 45px / 36px;*/
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        -o-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        border-radius: 45px / 38px;
        height: 41px;
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -17px;
        bottom: -17px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
    .full-circle:before {
        content:'';
        width: 47px;
        height: 26px;
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;
        left: -1px;
        top: -1px;
    }
    .text {
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: 0.99;
    }
```

```html
<button>News <span class="full-circle">
        <span class="text">+</span>
</span>
</button>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code from [this pen](http://codepen.io/xram/pen/thLsk).

```
div{
     height:45px;
     width:90px;
     border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     background:green;
}
```

Which gives you the half circle you're looking for, just upside-down.  To fix that and make it look like what you need:

```
div{
     height:23px;
     width:46px;
     border-radius: 0 0 46px 46px;
     -moz-border-radius:0 0 46px 46px;
     -webkit-border-radius:0 0 46px 46px;
     background:white;
     border-bottom:1px solid #1588cb;
     border-left:1px solid #1588cb;
     border-right:1px solid #1588cb;
}
```

With some nudging, you should be able to get that where you need it.

Comment: You're omnipresent, fauxserious!! :-D Thank you. Will try this out right now. Many thanks.

Comment: fauxserious's answer seems to work, but to **see** why yours does not you should add `* * { outline: 1px dotted red }`  (2 stars) as last line to your CSS.

Comment: It works great on Firefox. My only issue is the 'bottom' seems deeper on this. For instance, the new one: https://jsfiddle.net/p8jfnwa0/1/ but the old one: https://jsfiddle.net/p8jfnwa0/ Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Change the `height` property.

Comment: Thanks. Updated here: https://jsfiddle.net/p8jfnwa0/2/ Still doesn't look *as* good as it could. See it goes flat at the bottom whereas the original didn't. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: `Height` has to be half of 46px to get a proper circle feel, so 23px. Change `bottom` accordingly (to -24px).

Comment: Just nudge the `height`, `width`, and `border-radius` properties around until you get what you want.